# Pulling content from one website to another

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I want to pull content from one site to another, SEO is of the utmost importance. So Iframes are out the window. I cannot use PHP either, won't work on in the CMS.

I tried another solution:

```
$('#target-div').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio.php #whateverdiv');
```

But I just can't get it working. I'm stuck making this site in a crappy CMS (no choice) and I want to incorporate content from my own wordpress site. The goal is to pull content that is within a certain div and display it on the target site in a div.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security policies implemented at the browser level, pulling in content via an AJAX call from another domain is prohibited. You're going to have to either create a service locally, or work out some hand-shake with the other domain and the [CORS headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).